# Weird streaks on my screen

Tags: display

I have a machine with an AMD Radeon HD 6800 GPU and a Dell U3011 monitor (2560×1600 pixels, 32-bit color, 60 Hertz), they are connected via DVI-D. The operating system is Windows 7.

Sometimes I see weird streaks on my screen. I attached a picture of one of them: You can see my green desktop while I drag a rectangle with the mouse on it. These streaks appear also in other windows, e.g. Chrome, Notepad++, and almost any other program. They are always horizontal.

What can cause this? How can I prevent them from appearing?

[image]

Comment: Are the lines always in exactly the same location(s)?  Do you get multiple lines at the same time?  Are they always the same color?  Do they appear with some screen content but not others?  Does the appearance vary with the color of the screen content the line runs through?  Does it happen from the time you turn it on or start only after it's been on for awhile?  If you connect another display, does it appear there, also?  Can we assume that the rectangle was added just to frame the problem, it isn't what triggers it?

Comment: No they appear randomly. Yes, sometimes there are multiple lines. No, the color can change, the one on the picture is not of the same color, either (mainly green but contains blue, too). I didn't find a relationship between the background and the line.Sometimes it starts when I login, sometime only later. Sorry, I don't have another display. No, after the lines started to appear, I noticed that drawing a rectangle on the screen (e.g. to select icons on the desktop) can make such lines appear / disappear but could not figure out an exact relationship.

Comment: Just a guess that the problem is with the electronics in the monitor.  It looks like portions of a pixel row are getting sub-pixels turned on or off.  The only fix would be to get it serviced.